# How to mock tested class' member that is a list of objects and assert_called on object's method?

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I have the following scenario (simplified):

Project structure:

```
├── main.py
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── member.py
│   └── myclass.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_myclass.py
```

```py
# myclass.py
from .member import Member


class MyClass():
    members = []

    def __init__(self, one, *args):
        self.one = one
        for arg in args:
            self.members.append(Member(arg))

    def some_method(self, arg):
        [member.some_method(arg) for member in self.members]
```

```py
# member.py

class Member:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.prop = arg

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.prop}'

    def some_method(self, arg):
        print(f'[!] {repr(self)}')
```

As a testcase I want to assert that `some_method` was called for each member in MyClass.memebers.
I tried mock `src.myclass.MyClass.members` with Mock, MagicMock and finally with passing list of Members (example below). I really struggle to wrap my head around how I can do that.

```py
# test_myclass.py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from src.myclass import MyClass
from src.member import Member


class MyClassTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_myclass_some_method(self):
        with patch('src.myclass.MyClass.members', new=[
            Member('ten'),
            Member('eleven'),
            Member('thirteen')
        ]) as mock_members:
            MyClass.some_method(MyClass, 'four')
            # This is where I want to assert_called on Member
            mock_members[0].assert_called()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to test this by replacing each Member with a Magic Mock, and then testing if the method has been called:

```
class MyClassTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_myclass_some_method(self):
        with patch('src.myclass.MyClass.members', new=[
            MagicMock(),
            MagicMock(),
            MagicMock()
        ]) as mock_members:
            MyClass.some_method(MyClass, 'four')
            # This is where I want to assert_called on Member
            mock_members[0].some_method.assert_called()
```

Comment: That does not work unfortunately, it gives an error `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'assert_called'`

Comment: Thanks for the try @reed53, This is what I've been struggling with, seems that `MyClass.some_method` call is not referencing patched `members`.

Comment: That's weird, the test seems to pass on my computer. Something else may be wrong then

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with where you are running the tests from. I am using PyCharm, ran the test using a run configuration, and made sure to have src set to the sources root and added to PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 0):

To remove external dependency on `Member` class I added internal class within the testcase keeping only function I wanted to assert was called.
Then, I used MagicMock with internal class' instance to retain `some_method()` and to magically add `assert_called()`, and finally I instantiated `MyClass`.

I wanted to avoid creating MyClass object for two reasons:

1. because I wanted to unittest that specific function only, and
2. because this is a simplified example and real 'MyClass' has costly  dependencies to instantiate.

Not ideal but seems to work. Any comments on how this could be approached differently are very welcome.

```py
# test_myclass.py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock
from src.myclass import MyClass


class MyClassTest(unittest.TestCase):
    class Member:
        def some_method(self):
            pass

    def test_myclass_some_method(self):
        with patch('src.myclass.MyClass.members', new=[
            MagicMock(self.Member()),
            MagicMock(self.Member()),
            MagicMock(self.Member())
        ]):
            mc = MyClass('blah')
            mc.some_method('four')
            # assert_called() on each Member
            [member.some_method.assert_called() for member in mc.members]
```